# How to update parts of the state in a State monad?

Tags: haskell, monads, haskell-lens, state-monad

I have a type that I'd like to use as part of a state monad:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Control.Lens

data SomeState = SomeState
  { _int :: Int,
    _string :: String }
makeLenses ''SomeState
```

I have functions that operate on parts of the state in `SomeState`. Let's say they also use a state monad:

```
updateInt :: Int -> State Int ()
updateString :: String -> State String ()
```

On the top-level I have a functions that deal with the whole `SomeState`.

```
updateSomeState :: Int -> State SomeState ()
```

I would like to call `updateInt` and `updateString` as part of `updateSomeState`. I have the feeling it should be possible to "convert" the SomeState state monad into a state monad for one of its parts using lense, but I fail to see how.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can do this with the `zoom` combinator from `Control.Lens.Zoom`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Control.Lens
import Control.Monad.State
data SomeState = SomeState { _int :: Int, _string :: String } deriving (Show)
makeLenses ''SomeState
updateInt :: Int -> State Int ()
updateInt x = id .= x
updateString :: String -> State String ()
updateString x = id .= x

updateSomeState :: Int -> State SomeState ()
updateSomeState x = zoom int (updateInt x)
```

GHCi:

```
*Main> runStateT (updateSomeState 5) (SomeState 3 "hi")
 Identity ((),SomeState {_int = 5, _string = "hi"})
```